# WordPress: How to create a default value for an attribute in a Gutenberg Block

Tags: wordpress, attributes, default, gutenberg-blocks

Does anyone know how to create a default attribute value for all instances of a WordPress Gutenberg block on a given website?

I realise I can create an attribute with a default value but I'd like to be able to change the default value from the block.

I could make the attribute read only and therefore I'd have a default value for all instances of the block but that means I can't change the value without a rebuild and reinstallation.

Best Regards,

Steve

Comment: Has this block already been used on the website or are you being a new block?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have installed the block on one website so far.

Comment: I've replaced save.js with a php file. The advantage is that the block doesn't break or need refreshing after a change. It also means I can easily read a file on the server side with settings. It wouldn't be ideal but I could create an xml or json file and take default values from there. These could be changed but means ftp access to the file which isn't exactly ideal.

I suppose a further step could be to create a PHP plugin and allow it to edit the settings file. Would mean a separate 'admin' plugin but that's the best I can think of.